# use of BagOfVisualWord class in OpenImaj library

Tags: java, generics, openimaj

So in my case i should provide to computeQuantisedFeatures method two arguments , the second one is of type

```
        List<LocalFeature<Location, ? extends ArrayFeatureVector<byte[]>>>
```

i try to pass my imagekeypoints list which is of type

```
    LocalFeatureList<Keypoint>
```

and also

```
    List<LocalFeature<KeypointLocation, ByteFV>> features = null;
    for (java.util.Iterator<Keypoint> iter = imageKeypoints.iterator(); iter.hasNext();)
    {features.add((LocalFeature<KeypointLocation, ByteFV>)iter.next());}
```

but i always get the famous error

```
    The method computeQuantisedFeatures(HardAssigner<T,?,?>, List<LocalFeature<L,? 
    extends ArrayFeatureVector<T>>>) in the type BagOfVisualWords is not applicable for
    the arguments (HardAssigner<byte[],capture#3-of ?,capture#4-of ?>, 
    List<LocalFeature<KeypointLocation,ByteFV>>)
```

Answer (score 1):

Note: I based this answer on the `Keypoint` source [here](http://code.ohloh.net/file?fid=wx1t6y3ue5PkgGZAS3-vHzKJQJI&cid=N2mZo1S3wZ0&s=Keypoint.java&pp=0&fl=Java&ff=1&filterChecked=true&mp=0&ml=1&me=1&md=1&browser=Default#L32).

This problem arises from the fact that generics [aren't covariant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_and_contravariance_%28computer_science%29#Java). The method expects a `List<LocalFeature<L, ? extends ArrayFeatureVector<T>>>`, but you're providing a `List<Keypoint>`. If the method took a `List<? extends LocalFeature<L, ? extends ArrayFeatureVector<T>>>` instead, it would be a legal call.

The simplest solution is to copy the contents of `imagekeypoints` into a newly created `List<LocalFeature<KeypointLocation, ByteFV>>` and pass that into the call instead.

Comment: i try this but i still get same error
    
       ` List<LocalFeature<KeypointLocation, ByteFV>>
        imagekeypointsList = new 
        ArrayList<LocalFeature<KeypointLocation,ByteFV>>();  
 for (Keypoint key :imageKeypoints)
 {imagekeypointsList.add(key);}`
       
Not that hardassigner also is not applicable

Comment: Hmm, that should work. Did you try Jon's solution? Please update the question with your latest code and error if it still isn't working.

Comment: thanks paul    
yes i try it

problem is solved for assigner but not for features

i will update my question

Comment: Hmm, I think you're missing something basic here. According to the error you're still passing in the same `List<LocalFeature<KeypointLocation,ByteFV>>`.

Comment: yes , may be keypoints aren't the right choise

i hope Dr jon give me a suggestion

Answer (score 1):

As noted by Paul Bellora, this is actually a bug in the generics of that method. I've just committed a fix which will be available in the `1.1.1-SNAPSHOT` versions shortly. A temporary solution is to implement the correct version of the `computeQuantisedFeatures` method in your class as follows:

```
public static <L extends Location, T> List<QuantisedLocalFeature<L>> computeQuantisedFeatures(
    HardAssigner<T, ?, ?> assigner,
    List<? extends LocalFeature<L, ? extends ArrayFeatureVector<T>>> features)
{
    final List<QuantisedLocalFeature<L>> out = new ArrayList<QuantisedLocalFeature<L>>(features.size());

    for (final LocalFeature<L, ? extends ArrayFeatureVector<T>> f : features) {
        final int idx = assigner.assign(f.getFeatureVector().values);
        out.add(new QuantisedLocalFeature<L>(f.getLocation(), idx));
    }

    return out;
}
```